# JSF 2.0 Session Timeout throws IllegalStateException

Tags: jsf

I have to logout the user after session timeout. I am using an `EventListenter` to clear out the session and also a `PhaseListener` to validate the user before doing any processiong.

I am getting following exception when I try to click on any button after the session has timedout:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.reset(ResponseFacade.java:310)
com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.responseReset(ExternalContextImpl.java:821)
com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.throwIt(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:251)
com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:141)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:113)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:395)
```

My web.xml has following entries  :

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/content/country/default/jsp/login.faces</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/content/country/default/jsp/error.faces</location>
</error-page>
```

The piece of code from the PhaseListener is

```
try{
    log.info("------------Check the method call-----------");
    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.info("Authentication is needed.  Navigating to login page.");
    nh.handleNavigation(fc, null, NavigationConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE.toString());
    return;
}catch(ViewExpiredException ve){
    log.info("Got the view expired exception. . . ");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("login.faces");
}catch(IllegalStateException e){
    log.info("Got the IllegalStateException . . ");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("login.faces");
}catch(Exception ex){
    log.info("Got the Exception . . ",ex);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("login.faces");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.reset(ResponseFacade.java:310)
```

You got this exception [because](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#reset%28%29) the response has already been committed.

```
com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.responseReset(ExternalContextImpl.java:821)
com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.throwIt(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:251)
com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:141)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:113)
```

So, JSF encountered *an* exception during the restore view phase and needs to throw it (so that it ends up in the error page), however it was unable to do because the response was already been committed at that point (without JSF being informed that it should move on to render response immediately).

It's not clear when exactly this phase listener does its job, but your main interest would be figuring which exception exactly was been thrown during the restore view phase and also why the response is already committed at that point. This cannot be answered based on the code and information posted so far. Running a debugger should tell you more about the exception and tracking the code flow where you're committing the response should tell more about the unintended commit.

Regardless, your below functional requirement intrigues me:

> *I have to logout the user after session timeout. I am using an EventListenter to clear out the session*

I fail to understand why that's necessary. A logged-in user is normally represented as a session attribute. If the session get timed out, then the logged-in user should **already** automatically disappear. You don't need to take any cleanup actions yourself. You just have to check the *presence* of the logged-in user in the session whenever you need to do any actions based on it.

Comment: basically the application creates a auth token and logs it in the DB. The requirement is that it should be invalidated after session expires or user logs out. So i am trying to invalidate the auth token in sessionDestroy method. Let me run debugger and will get back to you if i get some clarity over it. Thanks

Comment: The `sessionDestroyed()` method of a `HttpSessionListener` implementation, you mean? I'd still wonder what that event listener and phase listener have to do with it. When exactly does that phase listener run?

Comment: Yes the phaseListener is in the afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) method, where we check for the user authentication. I am not sure if that piece of code is throwing exception or not. Also the same code works for some of the pages where we are doing direct call like /abc.faces but it does not work for <CommandLink action =""> basically for some clicks which calls the bean's specific methods.

Comment: Yes, but during which phase? As to the exception during postbacks, that can only mean that it's a `ViewExpiredException`, which is very normal as the session (and thus also the view state) has been expired. But your real problem is that the response is already committed at that point. It should not be committed at that point, or JSF should at least been told not to execute the lifecycle. What kind of page do you see in the browser? Are you somewhere calling `response.sendRedirect()` without blocking the rest of request/response? Maybe in some `Filter`?

Comment: I don't think i m doing response.sendRedirect, I am on one page while i m in session. Then the session expires and I click a button which goes to action of specific bean. That time it goes into the phaseListener and throws exception.